# JavaScript Math — Getting the Wrong Answer (128 - 64 = -64)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I am trying to produce a low-level performance comparison tool for graphics cards, and I have everything working just fine, except for the bus width comparison.

```js
var bl_bus = $('#baseline-ram-bus-width').val();
var tg_bus = $('#target-ram-bus-width').val();

// Memory Bus Width
    if (tg_bus < bl_bus) {
        $('#compare-bus-bl span').text("+" + (bl_bus - tg_bus));
        $('#compare-bus-tg span').text((tg_bus - bl_bus));
    }
    if (tg_bus === bl_bus) {
        $('#compare-bus-bl span').text("Equal");
        $('#compare-bus-tg span').text("Equal");
    }
    if (tg_bus > bl_bus) {
        $('#compare-bus-bl span').text((tg_bus - bl_bus));
        $('#compare-bus-tg span').text("+" + (bl_bus - tg_bus));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="baseline-ram-bus-width">Baseline Memory Bus Width:</label>
<input id="baseline-ram-bus-width" type="number" placeholder="Memory Bus Width (b)" value="128"> bits
<br>

<label for="target-ram-bus-width">Target Memory Bus Width:</label>
<input id="target-ram-bus-width" type="number" placeholder="Memory Bus Width (b)" value="64"> bits
<br><br>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Memory Bus Width</th>
        <td id="compare-bus-bl"><span>0</span> bits</td>
        <td id="compare-bus-tg"><span>0</span> bits</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As far as I can tell, I have coded it properly. In my example where the baseline is 128 bits, and the target is 64 bits, the first `if` statement should be used as the target bus width is less than the baseline.

However, the result is entirely different to what I expect. For some reason, JavaScript seems to think the answer is -64 bits for baseline, and +64 bits for target.

I've spent a few days trying to figure out why this has been happening, even going as far as to recode the entire file, but ending up with the same error. Can anyone shed some light on this, please? I have a feeling there's something blatantly obvious that I'm not noticing.

Comment: Do you have a debugger?

Comment: @Amit I have been using Opera's built-in WebKit debugger. No errors are given.

Comment: Does that debugger have breakpoints?

Comment: @mjohnsonengr I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. I'm by no means a JavaScript expert.

Comment: Your values are strings, you need to parseInt them

Comment: [Chrome's documentation on breakpoints](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#breakpoints)

Comment: I didn't go through your code but you are basically doing math with text. I'd expect to see `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` somewhere :-?

Comment: If you don't know what to do with a debugger, *study that*. It's more important than your wrong value. (BTW, a hint: your bug is in `if (tg_bus < bl_bus)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I parsed the values before doing any math.  Does this seem right?

```js
var bl_bus = parseInt( $('#baseline-ram-bus-width').val(), 10);
var tg_bus = parseInt( $('#target-ram-bus-width').val(), 10);

// Memory Bus Width
    if (tg_bus < bl_bus) {
        $('#compare-bus-bl span').text("+" + (bl_bus - tg_bus));
        $('#compare-bus-tg span').text((tg_bus - bl_bus));
    }
    if (tg_bus === bl_bus) {
        $('#compare-bus-bl span').text("Equal");
        $('#compare-bus-tg span').text("Equal");
    }
    if (tg_bus > bl_bus) {
        $('#compare-bus-bl span').text((tg_bus - bl_bus));
        $('#compare-bus-tg span').text("+" + (bl_bus - tg_bus));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="baseline-ram-bus-width">Baseline Memory Bus Width:</label>
<input id="baseline-ram-bus-width" type="number" placeholder="Memory Bus Width (b)" value="128"> bits
<br>

<label for="target-ram-bus-width">Target Memory Bus Width:</label>
<input id="target-ram-bus-width" type="number" placeholder="Memory Bus Width (b)" value="64"> bits
<br><br>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Memory Bus Width</th>
        <td id="compare-bus-bl"><span>0</span> bits</td>
        <td id="compare-bus-tg"><span>0</span> bits</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I will accept your answer for going with the standard JavaScript to parse integers as I feel that's more important to understand than the jQuery equivalent. I knew it would have been something silly like that.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure you are getting the values in integer format (As I corrected)

```js
var bl_bus = +$('#baseline-ram-bus-width').val();
var tg_bus = +$('#target-ram-bus-width').val();
```

Comment: jQuery is loaded in my file, I must have missed it out of the copy+paste. My apologies.

Comment: Should I use `+` or `parseInt()`?

Comment: While you are using jQuery, + is enough.
parseInt is a JS Native function

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: I decided to accept the other answer for providing the plain JavaScript as I feel that will help more people, but by no means is your answer any less credible. I will be using jQuery, so this helps me either way. Once again, thanks!